# what " setContentView " helps in

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, setcontentview

I tried to make a new Relativelayout, I then created a button, finally I added this button to the layout.
but what does " setContentView " help to achieve?

Here is the code

```
RelativeLayout wassimLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
Button redButton = new Button(this);
wassimLayout.addView(redButton);
setContentView(wassimLayout);
```

I don't know, but I feel it perhaps sets the buttons height, width and other characteristics to default. how do i prevent that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the issue you are having? `setContentView()` inflates the layout for that activity

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating views in code and not in the xml, you need to create and set LayoutParams for both the RelativeLayout and the Button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you wrote that correct because setContentView connects Java file with xml file and the correct way to do this is to write this

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
```

in main which in android is onCreate method.